# How to remove folder names from URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, web

I am making a page for training. This page has a blog with blogposts. I made a separate folder for my blog posts, but now I have a problem with this:
https://www.piximum.co/blogposts/blog1/Website-in-the-age-of-social-networks
I want to remove folder names (blogposts/blog1) from URL, but I couldn't find any working .htaccess code to do that. Can someone provide me some working .htaccess code for solving this problem?

Here is what I have tried:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews 
# Turn mod_rewrite on 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^blogposts/blog1/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```

This removes the folder names from link, but link is not going to my post.

Comment: What have you tried and what went wrong?

Comment: Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^blogposts/blog1/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]

And it's not working. This delete folder names from link, but link is not going to my post, it show's mistake.
http://prntscr.com/q16zaz

Comment: You need to do a better job a describing what you actually want here. The URL your screenshot shows in the address bar - is that the one you actually want to use in your links, in the URLs? And the actual file resides in the folder `blogposts/blog1` on the server? Then you are going in exactly the wrong direction here with your attempt - you are trying to match `blogposts/blog1` in the _requested_ URL, but that is not in there.

Comment: Yes, the link on the screenshot looks like I want to be. Folders are hidden. But problem is, when I hide folders, my page is not working (you see error page below).

Comment: As I said, you are trying to rewrite in the wrong direction. The code you have currently shown, matches only when the URL requested by the client starts with `blogposts/blog1/`, and then it _removes_ that from the internal URL. You want the exact opposite.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using an index file that handles all requests and prevent direct access to php files 
something like that:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'includes/autoloader.inc.php';

define('NotDirectAccess',True);
if (isset($_SESSION['mydata'])){
      if(isset($_GET['questions'])) {
        require_once 'View/questions.php';
      }else if(isset($_GET['tests'])) {
        require_once 'View/tests.php';
      }else if(isset($_GET['groups'])) {
        require_once 'View/groups.php';
      }else if(isset($_GET['courses'])) {
        require_once 'View/courses.php';
      }else if(isset($_GET['users'])) {
        require_once 'View/users.php';
      }else if(isset($_GET['results'])) {
        require_once 'View/results.php';
      }else if(isset($_GET['profile'])) {
        require_once 'View/profile.php';
      }else{
        require_once 'View/home.php';
      }
}else{
    if(isset($_GET['register'])) {
        require_once 'View/register.php';
    }else if(isset($_GET['reset'])) {
      require_once 'View/reset.php';
    }else{
        require_once 'View/login.php';
}}
```

and i added this at the beginning of each php file to prevent direct access to php files

```
if (!defined('NotDirectAccess')){
    die('Direct Access is not allowed to this page');
}
```